# margin of one div seems to affect whole site

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am creating a wordpress child theme based on twentythirteen.

```
<body class="home page page-id-2 page-template-default logged-in admin-bar no-customize-support single-author">
<div id="page" class="hfeed site">
<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
<a href="http://www.s2e.ee-web.co.uk/">
 <img src="http://www.s2e.ee-web.co.uk/wp-content/themes/s2e/images/space-to-earth-challenge-logo.jpg" alt="Space to Earth Challenge logo " class="s2e-logo" /></a>
<div class="edclearer"></div>
</header><!-- #masthead -->
<div id="topmenubar">
    <div class="topmenucontent">
        <p>hello</p>
    </div><!--topmenucontent-->
</div><!--topmenubar-->
```

When I put a `margin-top:40px` onto `#topmenubar` the whole site moves down from the top - when I use firebug to switch the margin off the whole site locks to the top. Noticed this is fine in IE but not in FF

Why is putting a margin on the `#topmenubar` reflected up at the top? How do I stop it?

Thanks

Here's my css

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

html {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

body {
    font-family:Arial;
    color:#fff;
    line-height:1.3;
}

.edclearer {clear:both;}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-family:Arial;
    color:#fff;
    font-weight:bold;
}

header, #main, footer
 {
    width:1170px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

#main { 
    background:none;
}

#navbar {
    display:none;
}

.site {
    background:none;
    margin:0;
    border:none;
}

#main {
    background:orange;
}

/* --- header --- */

.s2e-logo {
    float:left;
}

.headertext {
    width:400px;
    float:left;
    margin-top:110px;
    margin-left:74px;
    margin-left:6.3%;
    width:700px;
    width:65%;
}

.headertext p {
    font-family:'Oswald', serif;
    font-weight:400;
    color:#fff;
    line-height:1.5;
    font-size:26px;
}

.headerrightblock {
    float:right;
    margin-top:35px;
    text-align:right;
    width:200px;
    width:13.6%;
}

.sm-logo {
    margin-left:11px;
    display:inline-block;
}

.sm-logo:first-child {
    margin-left:0;
}

.principa-logo {
    float:right;
    margin-top:50px;
}
```

Comment: Can you please send your site link?

Comment: @Ravi Kumar it's not good posting direct links to sites!

Comment: Are you checking on the same browser in which you are logged in as a admin?

Comment: good question! I looked in IE and its fine. But in FF there is the extra space. And I am not logged in as admin

Comment: Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: This kind of problems often occurs with first elements in layout flow that have a margin. Usually changing `margin-top` to `padding-top` is enough to get over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give the header a certain height (or even a 100%) and secondly, adding an overflow hidden value - it should fix it for Firefox.

Try the following CSS:

```
.site-header {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: thanks - I set a height and it worked. Don't suppose you know why do you?

Answer (score -2):

The problem is in the logo, because you are floating it, and you don't need to float it. Floats causes break layouts. Be careful with this. The right floated elements are fine, it's because I don't remove them. Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/s9utbzyr/

And the code is only remove float from logo:

```
  .s2e-logo {
  }
```

You can add a `display:inline-block` to it if you don't want that element's behaviour will be simple `inline`.